# Django admin, Use ImportExportModelAdmin and MarkdownxModelAdmin (Multiple)

Tags: django, django-admin, markdown, django-import-export

I have model Product.
1) There is markdownx field (from django-markdownx package) and I want use markdown editor in admin
2) I use import-export in admin for this model.

I can make *import-export** works by using **ImportExportModelAdmin**:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
class ProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin): [some_code...]
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

I can make **markdownx** works by using **MarkdownxModelAdmin**:

```
from markdownx.admin import MarkdownxModelAdmin
class ProductAdmin(MarkdownxModelAdmin): [some_code...]
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

How to make them both works?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by inheriting multiple python classes as follows:

```
from markdownx.admin import MarkdownxModelAdmin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class ProductAdmin(MarkdownxModelAdmin): 
    [some_code...]

class ProductImportExport(ImportExportModelAdmin, ProductAdmin): 
    [some_code...]

admin.site.register(Product, ProductImportExport)
```